# tryCatch in R: handling a non-numeric vector

Tags: r

I'm completely new to using tryCatch in R. Here is my code:

```
# Outputs outliers

outlier <- function(vector){

  #error handling if vector can't be converted to numeric vector
  vector <- tryCatch(expr = as.numeric(vector),
                     error = {message("The vector is not numeric.")
                              return(NULL)})

  #calculate IQR (i.e., Q_3 - Q_1)
  IQR <- diff(quantile(vector, probs = c(0.25, 0.75), names = FALSE))

  #calculate lower fence and upper fence
  LF <- quantile(vector, probs = 0.25, names = FALSE) - 1.5 * IQR
  UF <- quantile(vector, probs = 0.75, names = FALSE) + 1.5 * IQR

  #find values of vector which are either less than the lower fence
  #or greater than the upper fence of data.

  return(vector[which(vector < LF | vector > UF)])

}
```

For example,

```
> outlier(c(-25, 0, 1, 2))
The vector is not numeric.
NULL
```

This obviously shouldn't be happening. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your error message into a function:

```
vector <- tryCatch(expr = as.numeric(vector),
                   warning = function(w) {
                       message("The vector is not numeric.")
                       return(NULL)
                   })
```

Should work.

Comment: Now it spits out `logical(0)` for the output, but if I do `outlier(c("A", "B", "C"))`, I don't have the `"The vector is not numeric."` message pop up. It also says `logical(0)`.

Comment: It actually should be warning. Because `as.numeric(c("A", "B", "C"))` doesn't give error message but warning.

Comment: Oh wait, ignore that last comment. Thank you, it works!